# Enhanced ecommerce don't recognize internal promotion view object

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I've been implementing all the enhanced eCommerce tracks for the past few weeks and I could do most of the job successfully thanks to Simo Ahava's [blog](https://www.simoahava.com/v). But now I'm struggling with the internal promotion view tracking.

I choose to implement the view tracking with the concept of [True View Impressions](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/true-view-impressions-google-tag-manager/#commento-login-box-container) also with a base on Simo's work and for products it was ok. So I modified the customTasks from the link to track internal promotion but, for some reason, the enhanced eCommerce isn't recognizing the promoView object. But it's recognizing the promoClick (?).

I've made a test: I substitute the promoClick for a impression object and it works! So, my strong guest, it's that the problem it's really on my object. My object's format can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55VGt.jpg).

And to illustrate the way the object it's being constructed:

```
      var targetElement = {{Click Element}},
      event         = {{Event}},
      batch         = window[promoBatchVariableName],
      impressions   = google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}].dataLayer.get('ecommerce.promoView.promotions'),
      ecomObj       = { };

  if (event === 'gtm.click') {
    while (!targetElement.getAttribute(promoIdAttribute) && targetElement.tagName !== 'BODY') {
      targetElement = targetElement.parentElement;
    }
  }

  var latestPromoImpression = impressions.filter(function(impression) {
    return impression.id === targetElement.getAttribute(promoIdAttribute);
  }).shift();

  var promoImpressionsArr = batch.map(function(id) {
    return impressions.filter(function(impression) {
      return impression.id === id;      
    }).shift();
  });

  if (event === 'gtm.elementVisibility'){
    promoImpressionsArr[maxPromoBatch - 1] = latestPromoImpression;
  }

  console.log(ecomObj)
  ecomObj.promoView = { promotions: promoImpressionsArr};

  if (event === 'gtm.click') {
    ecomObj.promoClick = {
      promotions: [latestPromoImpression]
    };
    console.log("click")
  }

  return {
    ecommerce: ecomObj
  };
}
```

Could someone help me with some ideas?

Comment: The Simo ahava blog is very useful, often better than the Google documentation. You say that you have successfully implemented most of the enhanced ecommerce datalayers. Are they generated by the GTM itself or are they created on the website backend? I ask this because you commented that you modified the custom task to carry out this implementation of promoclicks and impressions. looking at the image, it looks like the promo array comes with some undefined. Have you tried to inspect the network to see if this data is passed to Google Analytics?

Comment: I've done most of the work through GTM, in the funnel's steps as details, checkout, and purchase I've constructed an object using custom javascript variable and for impressions and clicks, I get a generic array from the dataLayer and modified it to be an eCommerce object. This array in the image is from a page in which some data still don't have the id but the eCommerce should just ignore them and recognize the rest. If I put the same data into a product impression object it works well. The data is not passing to GA, I let the code configured for some days and I didn't get a single hit.

Comment: Can you paste the promo click and promo impression datalayers ? I believe there is something wrong (it must be something simple, but structural) Another tip: since the datalayers are modified by GTM to then be used and sent to GA, did you try to use a hardcode datalayers to see if the data 'appears' in GA?

Comment: My promo impression object looks like this https://imgur.com/1wGLk3k on dataLayer, the promo click I don't send to dataLayer but it's working fine. Yes, I've been debugging the javascript and the data is appearing but when the GTM tries to send the data, the eCommerce is not recognized.

Comment: I noticed something strange in your image, maybe it's the editor, but it looks like you have an array of arrays when it should be a hash array (with key and values). Makes sense?

Comment: Hmm I didn't get it rs What's a hash of arrays? I'm starting with js now. x) But I think that is not this because my product impression object is the same and it works https://imgur.com/Hsv994Z

Comment: I think that you follow this long tutorial to help with the implementation of enhanced eCommerce : https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enhanced-ecommerce-guide-for-google-tag-manager/#promotion-views. Looking for the promotion views, the itens are in {} , nested by array []. Can you provide a screenshoot for the product impression in the network (developers console) or the website ?

Comment: Hi @LuizLai, I found the problem. And it's not on my object itself only. xD The problem is the undefined elements as you pointed at the beginning of our talk. I'm waiting for the dev team to change the data-attributes of the elements on our site's pages because sometimes we don't get any individual identifier variable. So, in the meantime, I've implemented a way to get always a product id even in these cases but as the identifier doesn't exist in the CSS selector if the element has an id in the 'entrance object', the element is set as undefined.

Comment: Wonderful. I hope you can get through with implementation. based on your comments, I was able to conclude that its implementation (maybe i am wrong) part of the construction of the datalayers is not in the backend but generated with the help of GTM and some elements of the frontend. You must be very careful, as any change on the front could break the data collection for enhanced ecommerce.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we are in close contact with the dev teams to track any changes that may compromise the data collection. Thank you for all help and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just to close the question! As I pointed in the comments:

" I found the problem. And it's not on my object itself only. xD The problem is the undefined elements as you pointed at the beginning of our talk. I'm waiting for the dev team to change the data-attributes of the elements on our site's pages because sometimes we don't get any individual identifier variable. So, in the meantime, I've implemented a way to get always a product id even in these cases but as the identifier doesn't exist in the CSS selector if the element has an id in the 'entrance object', the element is set as undefined. "